# htaccess rule to ignore specific subdomain

Tags: htaccess

I have a .co.uk domain name which hosts a Wordpress website and has SSL certificate applied via AutoSSL in cPanel.

I also have a subdomain to that .co.uk which is forwarding to another server using the DNS zone editor in WHM.

On the wordpress website, there is a link to the subdomain which should display a web app hosted on the secondary server, but unfortunately it is just reloading the wordpress website, and I am presuming this is something to do with the htaccess file.

Is there a rule that needs adding to make the htaccess ignore the subdomain so that when the link is clicked, the user is sent to the subdomain correctly, instead of having it refresh the home page?

Thanks

Comment: What DNS record are you using to "forward" the domain to another server? (Presumably an `A` record?) Does the subdomain work as expected when typing it directly in the browser's address bar? How is the link formed on your HTML page? The point is, if the subdomain is pointing to a different server (IP address) in the DNS then you shouldn't even be getting to your server, WordPress or `.htaccess`?! Make sure you've cleared your local browser/DNS caches.

Comment: there is nothing wordpress specific about this question. it sounds like either you do not have the right DNS configuration or you have not waited long enough for it to propagate.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes using an A record, typing the subdomain in works on some browsers but not others, the link is just a simple a href="http://...."

Comment: @MarkKaplun I did think that but then thought if it was htaccess causing this then best post in Wordpress topic, apologies if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have asked my hosting support to check my DNS and there were 2 entries because I added an A record in WHM and also added the subdomain to the account in cpanel, they have removed one and all is now working.

Apologies for posting in Wordpress, not technically Wordpress related as I first thought.

Comment: By creating a subdomain in cPanel you will have created an `A` record pointing to the local server. If you have more than one `A` record for the same hostname then the browser effectively picks one at random (or not, depending on implementation and DNS caches, etc.) so it's quite probable that user-agents see one result or the other. This is a form of [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).